# Asignación de roles con laravel-entrust

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel, permisos

Estoy trabajando en la creación de usuarios y asignacion de roles desde la vista para luego pasarlas al controlador. Una vez que guardo el usuario, trato de registrar el rol, pero al hacerlo me genera el siguiente error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

¿Qué podrá estar ocasionando ese error?

Anexo el codigo del controlador:

```
$user = new User;
$user->card = $request->card;
$user->name = $request->name;
$user->last_name = $request->last_name;
$user->login = $request->login;        
$user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
$user->save();

$role_id = $request->role_id;
$rol = Role::where('id', '=', $role_id)->get();
$user->roles()->attach($rol->id); //Aca me genera el error.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al utilizar el método `get()` estás obteniendo una colección, NO un solo elemento.

La colección como tal no tiene la propiedad `id`, quien la tiene es el objeto o elemento.

Puedes solucionarlo de dos formas:

1. Si de antemano sabes que solo vas a (deberías) obtener un registro, entonces puedes usar el método `first()`:

   ```
   $rol = Role::where('id', '=', $role_id)->first();
   $user->roles()->attach($rol->id);
   ```
2. Si definitivamente necesitas utilizar `get()` por alguna razón, debes entonces referenciar el elemento que necesitas, posiblemente sea el primero:

   ```
   $rol = Role::where('id', '=', $role_id)->get();
   $user->roles()->attach($rol[0]->id);
   ```

Comment: Solucionado, gracias amigo!!!